# python selenium fill an answer form on 3 webpages in a row

Tags: python, selenium

I am using the code below to fill an answer form on a webpage. If a key in the dictionary is found, it fills the answer form with the corresponding value:

```
secuQA = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}
q_element = browser.find_element_by_id("secu_ques")
question_strings = q_element.text.split(" ")

for key in secuQA:
    if key in question_strings:
        ans = secuQA[key]    
        ansElem = browser.find_element_by_id("secu_answ")
        ansElem.click()
        ansElem.send_keys(ans)
        ansElem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        break
```

3 such pages appear in a row (same format, just with different random questions). How do I make the code fill the answer forms on all 3 pages?

Comment: Loop through pagination. And put your code inside that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all the pages, adding some wait statements to make your code more robust. Something along the lines of:

```
#necessary imports 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


secuQA = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}


for question in range(3): # loop through 3 pages

    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "secu_ques"))) # wait until the question has been loaded on the page

    q_element = browser.find_element_by_id("secu_ques")
    question_strings = q_element.text.split(" ")

    for key in secuQA:
        if key in question_strings:
            ans = secuQA[key]    
            ansElem = browser.find_element_by_id("secu_answ")
            ansElem.click()
            ansElem.send_keys(ans)
            ansElem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            break

    time.sleep(1)#lets wait a while to the next page to load
```